# Using attr_accessor in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, attr-accessor

I've always had consistency problems with attr_accessor in rails.  I've never figured out what detail I am missing...so, I thought I would put a question here.

I have the following:

```
  ...Controller
  new
     @something = Something.new
     @something.it_should = true
  end
```

.

```
  ....Model
  attr_accessor :it_should

  def should_validate?
     it_should
  end

  validates_presence_of :name, :if => :should_validate?
```

So, I set the instance variable in the controller to true.  I make that variable available to the model via attr_accessor.  I put the variable into a method, then I use that method in the validation.  Seems like it should work.  But, it does nothing.  it_should is never set to true. The the page loads fine, but field is not validated.

I even tried this...but, it didn't cause the validation to execute.

```
  def should_validate?
     true
  end
```

What are the tricks for using att_accessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the instance variable `@it_should` which you set with the `attr_accessor` is not persisted between requests, so although you set it to `true` in your `new` action, it will be reset as soon as the form is submitted and some other action (probably `create` or `update`) is triggered.

If you want to validate a field this way, you'd have to set it in the action triggered by the form submission, e.g. `create`:

```
def create
  @something = Something.new(params[:something])
  @something.it_should = true
  @something.save
  ...
end
```

This should trigger the validation on `name` as expected.

Comment: Im hoping to make the conditional validation work with client_side_validations.  Therefor, having the it_should instance persistent only in the new action should still work.  Railscasts #41 discusses this topic, my set up is the same as Ryans...but mine doesnt work.

Comment: Do you assume the it_should variable is being set in the controller?  How could it not? The method in the model used for the conditional validation seems to be passing false no matter what.  However, if I skip the method and just do :if => :it_should == "random text", the validation acts as if true was the result.  Weird.

Comment: Just looking at the code in that Railscast, he has the lines `@user.updating_password = true` and `@user.save` in the same controller action, which would work (as I indicated above). But the way you've defined it will not work, because instance variables are not passed between requests.

Comment: Indeed, I just watched the Railscast and I think you've misunderstood how Ryan implemented this validation. He uses the `attr_accessor` to set the instance variable in a controller action called `update_password`. But unlike what you have written above, the record is saved *in the same action* that the instance variable is set, so there is no persistence issues.

Comment: I can't explain the weird behaviour you notice, but in any case what you're trying to do (as you've described it) is not possible. If you want to trigger the validation from the `new` action you'll have to send the trigger through requests, either through a session variable or as a query parameter. Or you can implement it as Ryan did (and as I suggested above) directly in the action that is saving the record.

Comment: p.s. this: `:if => :it_should == "random text"` will not work as a conditional, you cannot evaluate an expression like that in the options unless you pass a `Proc`, e.g. `:if => Proc.new { |instance| instance.it_should == "random text" }`. See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless).